# Covering a Cube with a Square

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, recreational-mathematics

Suppose you are given a single unit square, and you would like to completely cover the surface
of a cube by cutting up the square and pasting it onto the cube's surface.

> **Q1**. What is the largest cube that can be covered by a $1 \times 1$ square when cut into at most $k$ pieces?

The case $k=1$ has been studied, probably earlier than this reference:
 "Problem 10716: A cubical gift," *American Mathematical Monthly*, 108(1):81-82, January 2001,
solution by Catalano-Johnson, Loeb, Beebee.

          
[image: Square Wrapping Cube]
(This was discussed in an
[MSE Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76660/).)
The depicted solution results in a cube edge length of
$1/(2\sqrt{2}) \approx 0.35$.

As $k \to \infty$, there should be no wasted overlaps in the covering of the 6 faces,
and so the largest cube covered will have edge length
$1/\sqrt{6} \approx 0.41$.  What partition of the square leads to this optimal cover?

> **Q2**. For which value of $k$ is this optimal reached?

I have not found literature on this problem for $k>1$, but it seems likely it has been explored.
Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: I wonder if anyone in the packaging industry has the answer.


Comment: I believe there was a "Mathematical Games" column on dissections which had a Greek cross rearranged into a square.  Perhaps that article also mentioned this problem?  Gerhard "Testing Your Martin Gardner Fu" Paseman, 2012.05.04

Comment: If memory serves, Martin Gardner is also a source for the puzzle of covering a unit cube with a properly folded 1x7 strip.

Comment: Cool! The solution to that 1x7 puzzle informs the answer to the following: over all rectangles which can be folded to cover the unit cube, what is the lim inf of their areas?  Gerhard "Hint: The Answer Is Six" Paseman, 2017.04.03.

Comment: When I read the title I thought it was about a 2D version $\varphi:[0,1]^2\to[0,1]^3$ of Peano area-filling (or space-filling) curves $[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Four pieces, using the tessellation technique I learned from
Harry Lindgren's *Geometric Dissections* (1964):

[image]

Comment: I've  been looking for that!  Gerhard "Was It Behind The Headboard?" Paseman, 2017.04.01.

Comment: Also, if you shift the (smaller) black squares a little to the right, the one piece that almost looks like two pieces looks more like one piece.  Gerhard "Tilting His Head Over This" Paseman, 2017.04.01.

Comment: Beautiful! I posted [a colorized version](http://mathoverflow.net/a/266092/6094) to make the dissection of the net more self-evident.

Comment: Thanks!  GerPas: Yes, the hexomino tessellation cqn be moved a bit to the right
(and independently also a bit up, though that doesn't help your cause).
JO'R: I see that you were also the one who made a three-dimensional
model of a cube covered by 5 pieces of a square, but evidently it will
take more time (if you bother to do it at all) to re-do for the new
4-piece record.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: I'll make the model eventually, as there will be a certain pleasure in seeing your dissection fully deployed.

Comment: That was quick (especially for "eventually")!

Answer (score 26):

You can cut a $\sqrt{6}\times\sqrt{6}$ square into 24 pieces that then cover the $1\times1\times1$ cube. Two triangles from the figure below plus one parallelogram make up one $1\times1$square. parts of pieces sticking out to the left can obviously fit back in the right, so 18 pieces, plus 6 parts sticking out equals 24. You can improve on this by stitching pieces across the cube edge to make one bent piece and by stitching some of the parallelograms back to the triangles.

![cube.png][1]

---

[*Added by O'Rourke*:] Just to make Yoav's construction more explicit, here is how two triangles and
a parallelogram fit together to form a $1 \times 1$ square:

[image: Square sliced in three parts]

[*Added by Kallus*:] Here's an illustration of a construction similar to Fedja's construction but with only five pieces. The first figure is the $\sqrt{6}\times\sqrt{6}$ square. The second is the $2\times3$ rectangle, which we fold into a cube by taking away the two yellow squares, folding the remainder, and adding the squares as the two missing faces.

[image: Square broken into 6 pieces]
[image: Rectangle broken into 6 pieces]

[*Added by O'Rourke*:]
 [image: Photos of cube]

Comment: Brilliant!! :-)

Comment: Actually, any two polygons of the same area are equidecomposable and the surface of the cube can be unfolded into a polygon, so the result is nice but not terribly surprising. Of course, the question about the minimal number of pieces remains.

Comment: Assuming that "pieces" mean "connected polygonal pieces", we can take a 3 by 2 rectangle, cut it into a T-shape and two unit squares and then use the standard "sliding cut" to turn it into a square, giving the total of 6 pieces to cover the unit cube. Can we do better? 

Comment: Fedja, that's a great improvement on my extremely lazy effort! I like your construction, but I made an illustration of a slightly more symmetrical version of it, which I find a little more pleasing.

Comment: Changed answer to CW.

Comment: OK. Posted to soon earlier. The change from the T tetromino to the S tetromino actually allows going down to five pieces instead of six.

Comment: Wow!  $\mbox{}$

Comment: If I haven't messed up, another five piece construction starts with cutting a 2 by sqrt(6) rectangle from the square, cutting an L shape out of the corner, and use the remaining pieces to form another L shape.  This covers four faces of the cube with the cut lines being on cube edges and not on the faces.  Gerhard "Pretty Is In Beholder's Eye" Paseman, 2012.05.04

Comment: Hmm. Maybe the above L shaped suggestion involves 6 pieces.  Gerhard "Let Me Count Them Again" Paseman, 2012.05.04

Comment: As I discovered after posting http://mathoverflow.net/a/263267, one can cut down the vertical middle of the 2x3 rectangle (forming two 1x3's) for another 5 piece cover, with pieces whose shapes are easier to manage in practice, with the same small triangle piece as being the smallest bit of paper to handle.  Gerhard "Thinking In Mass Production Terms" Paseman, 2017.03.29.

Comment: Also, if you are clever about folding and stacking, this involves only two straightedge cuts and one fold, whereas the dissection above needs at least two folds to reduce the number of straightedge cuts to two.  Gerhard "Time Is Money Is Product" Paseman, 2017.03.29.

Answer (score 16):

Just illustrating [Noam Elkies' 4-piece solution](https://mathoverflow.net/a/266073/6094):

---

[image: Elkies4Piece]

---

[image: ElkiesCube3D]

<sup>Bottom face is mostly yellow (except for a little green); two hidden back faces are mauve.</sup>

---

Comment: Lol, I can't believe you actually made a model of it. I haven't used glue and paper and scissors to cut out shapes since arts and crafts in elementary school. Though this is significantly more complicated. The wide breadth of tasks that comes with the profession of mathematics, lol.

Answer (score 11):

*Sorry, this is an answer to an other question. (I did not read the question carefully.)*

**Question:** *For which $k$, $k$ squares can tile the surface of cube.*

**Answer:** $k=6\cdot(n^2+m^2)$.

Here is a tiling with $k=30$, $n=1$ and $m=2$.

[image: k=30]
<sub>(source: [psu.edu](https://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/wiki/2-1.png))</sub>

It is obvious if the tiling is vertex-to-vertex.

If the tiling is not vertex-to-vertex, you get a closed geodesic formed by overlaping sides.
Then you can shift squares on one side of the geodesic to make the tiling "more vertex-to-vertex".
Repeating this operation you can make the tiling to be vertex-to-vertex.

Comment: @Anton: Did you intend $n \ge 1 , m \ge 1$, or, say, $n \ge 1 , m \ge 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, $k$ has to be positive; so $n\ge 1$ and $m\ge 0$.

Comment: @Anton: Sorry to be slow :-/, but could you describe a partition of the square into 6 pieces that exactly cover the cube?

Comment: @Joseph: the partition into faces (the cube has 6 faces). 

Comment: @Anton: I apologize for being so dense, but it may be that you are answering a different question than I asked...? I asked for how to cut up *one* square to cover a cube, not how to cover a cube with many squares. If I've diagnosed this correctly (unsure), it may explain why we seem to be talking past one another?

Comment: Sorry I did not read it carefully. I will make a remark about that.

Comment: Still, a very nice answer to that other question!

Answer (score 5):

No promises that these are optimal, but here are some lower bounds:

With $k=2$, side length $3/8=0.375$ (with one piece flipped over),
and with $k=3$, side length $2/5=0.4$:

[image: http://flic.kr/p/cUzrg9]

[image: http://flic.kr/p/cUzrjL]